# Parsing Json data sent by android clinet using "post" request in django view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to loop around a json data sent by my android client. I used the code below but its not working for me. Any possible error that I am doing...????

```
def api_json(request):
    try:
        x101=json.loads(request.body)
        print x101
        for data in x101:
            print data+"xp"
            asset_code=data['asset_code']
            credential=data['credential']
            d1=data['d1']
            d2=data['d2']
            d3=data['d3']
            angle=data['angle']
            status=data['status']
            operator=data['operator']
            location=data['location']
            print asset_code,credential,d1,d2,d3,angle,status,operator,location
            v=Verification(asset_code=asset_code,
                          scan_time=datetime.datetime.now(),
                          credential=credential,
                          d1=d1,
                          d2=d2,
                          d3=d3,
                          angle=angle,
                          status=status,
                          operator=operator,
                          location=location,
                          image='')
            v.save()
    except:
        print 'nope'
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

error trace:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: is it printing 'nope'? I'd remove the giant try/except and figure out where the error is coming from.

Comment: yeah its printing nope

Comment: where does 'request' come from? if it is the requests library, you can use r = request.json to load json, instead of body.

Comment: *but its not working for me* is **not** a problem description. How is it not working for you? If you remove the blanket except handling (always a bad idea) what happens then?

Comment: philshem data is coming from android client

Comment: remove the try-except and update the question with the error stack trace please.

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Martijn Pieters  I updated my question with error log

Comment: that means that your 'data' is a string, and not a dict

Comment: ma ke laude doing negative voting, instead of giving fix

Comment: @PK10: That's just the exception; not the full traceback. What line raises that?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I am getting something like this when I printing x101 {u'status': u'1', u'credential': u'wqw2323ds2', u'angle': u'10', u'asset_code': u'XPS1020', u'location': u'Bangalore', u'operator': u'pradeep', u'd2': u'2', u'd3': u'3', u'd1': u'1'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON decodes to a dictionary, `for data in x101` iterates through the *keys* of that dictionary. So `data['d1']` will give the TypeError that you see, "string indices must be integers".

Since you have given absolutely no details about what the data structure actually looks like, we can only guess, but you perhaps want to iterate through the dict's *values* with `for data in x101.values()`.

In any case, you should definitely remove that try/except that does nothing except print "nope". Errors are there for a reason, and silencing them will only prevent you from debugging properly, as we see here.

**Edit**

x101 is just a single dict. You say that there will frequently be more than one dict, but it can't possibly work like that: the only way to have multiple dicts is to have them inside a list (ie a JSON array). And if so, they would have to *always* be in a list, even when there is just one. So your structure should be:

```
[
  {
    "angle": "10", 
    "asset_code": "XPS1020", 
    "credential": "wqw2323ds2", 
    "d1": "1", 
    "d2": "2", 
    "d3": "3", 
    "location": "Bangalore", 
    "operator": "pradeep", 
    "status": "1"
  }
]
```

and then your code will work as is, whether there is a single dict or many.

Comment: yeah Danial I removed try/except and I am getting same error as you pointed "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: And to debug when I am printing x101 I am Getting something like this    {u'status': u'1', u'credential': u'wqw2323ds2', u'angle': u'10', u'asset_code': u'XPS1020', u'location': u'Bangalore', u'operator': u'pradeep', u'd2': u'2', u'd3': u'3', u'd1': u'1'}

Comment: Well, then x101 is just a single dict, and you don't want to iterate through it at all. Simply access it directly - ie remove the for statement, and use `x101` instead of `data` everywhere.

Comment: but it expected that many time there will be more that one dict separated by comma(,) then how to handle and update them in model